# How can I request the removal of (misspelled) tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was browsing through the tags on Stack Overflow and found several misspelled ones. For example, the tag [sql-srever](/questions/tagged/sql-srever) was created a few hours ago.

Is there any way to request removal of tags? How come these obviously misspelled tags exist at all? How can they pass the reviews, or are new tags not reviewed?

Comment: Just correct the tag. If there are no questions with that particular tag any more, it will be gone after at most a day.

Comment: Such tags are usually created by sheer mistake; users with enough reputation can create new tags and not always bother to check after posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already been fixed.

But in general just make the edit to the question(s) yourself to correct the typo or, if you don't have the required reputation suggest an edit.

Unused tags are culled every 24 hours so it will soon disappear never to be suggested again (until the next person mistypes it).

Comment: How do you suggest an edit? I can edit the summary and the wiki of tags, but not the name, and I can't find a way to suggest an edit? Or do you mean suggest an edit here at meta?

Comment: @DanielHedberg - Edit the question(s) that have the bad tag.